# sql "WITH" оператор

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

```sql
ALTER TABLE s ADD COLUMN phone CHAR(10) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT ‘?’
```

В задании по ПБД спросили что будет с таблицей после этого запроса.
одногруппы предлагают ответ "добавится столбец Phone(знаковый длиной 10 символов) в таблице s, значение по умолчанию - ?"
но я не понимаю зачем в этом запросе WITH и не должен ли быть ответ "ничего не изменится, в запросе ошибка".
для пояснения - это просто теоретическое задание как я понял без конкретной программы

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если задание теоретическое, то зависит от СУБД и может где-то и есть такая, которая поддерживает данный синтаксис. Но вообще да, будет ошибка как из-за слова with, так и из-за странных кавычек ‘?’, если говорить о mysql.